# Can not find directory in Android

Tags: android, directory

I am trying to access a directory at `Device storage> DCIM > MyDir`.

What I've tried so far-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   File DcimDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString());

    File myDir=new File(DcimDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyDir");

    //I also tried
    //File myDir=new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MyDir");

    if (myDir.exists()){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In either case, it says directory not exits.  Any help?

> UPDATE:
>    My Android version is 5 (Lollipop), API level-21. Don't have any external SD card.

Answer (score 2):

What Android version are you testing your application on?

Because if it's on Android 6.0 or higher, you need to set so called Runtime Permissions to be able to access the external storage.

This link provides a nice explanation and an implementation for those special permissions:
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

You can also look it up on the official Android Developers website:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

I hope this helps

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Have u added the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes. I've that permission.